# flightstats and jQuery - callback failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I've been trying to query the flightstats API and I'm now (I think) at the final hurdle.. I have a working ajax request/response which returns the correct data, however the error function is always called rather than success. Its because of the way the callback parameter is used but I have no idea what's required and can't find documentation.

Below is my code, bear in mind that if I leave out the callback parameter I get the same error text as if I include it using "&callback=...", "&callback=?", "?callback=..." or "?callback=?" because in each f those cases jQuery adds another callback parameter!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/flight/status/QF/1/dep/2013/08/22?appId=<appId>&appKey=<appKey>&utc=false',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#response').html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //do with ajax errors
        console.log('Fail: ' + thrownError);
    }
});
```

and the console.log error:

```
Fail: Error: jQuery110105137549804057926_1377341987289 was not called
```

Comment: Its fixed - using the code below.

$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/jsonp/flight/status/QF/1/dep/2013/08/22?appId=741be83f&appKey=08293e9e8eb43a5eb7b375d0e5cc1737&utc=false',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'flightstatus',
          //jsonpCallback: 'flightstatus',
          success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                  
          error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); }
        });

Answer (score 1):

If the called URL, in this case:

https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/flight/status/QF/1/dep/2013/08/22?appId=&appKey=&utc=false

doesn't return HTTP 200 OK code, then your error function will be triggered.

Comment: It is returning HTTP 200 OK - perhaps I wasnt clear enough, its getting the correct response as well as the json data.

I've read this on the jquery site.. I can see this is a jquery question now nothing to do with the API..
 
"When data is retrieved from remote servers (which is only possible using the script or jsonp data types), the error callbacks and global events will never be fired."

So, it shouldnt be firing the error function. Ive removed it now but getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 22:1" which is in the json data. I'll continue looking at jquery docs.

Comment: This is impossible for us to tell without seeing an SSCCE from you but I've also noticed that you haven't specified a jsonpCallback function and you haven't specified contentType. Maybe you should take a look at a working example here: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/ and use one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix, the code is below. I hadnt specified jsonp in the request so the format being returned was plain json, I also didnt understand the nuances of jsonp and figured it out thru other stackoverflow questions.

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/jsonp/flight/status/QF/1/dep/2013/08/22?appId=<appId>&appKey=<appKey>&utc=false',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'flightstatus',
          //jsonpCallback: 'flightstatus',
          success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                  
          error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); }
        });
```