# Flightstats and jQuery callback failure 2

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am having the same problem as

[flightstats and jQuery - callback failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417909/flightstats-and-jquery-callback-failure)

The last entry on above topic SBignell entered code which worked for him.  I tried using the same code and I still can't get it to work.  If I submit the URL in a browser, it returns FlightStats data just fine.  I just can't get the script to do the same not matter what I try.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.   Here's my exact code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/jsonp/flight/status/QF/1/dep  /2013/09/04?appId=741be83f&appKey=08293e9e8eb43a5eb7b375d0e5cc1737&utc=false',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'flightstatus',
      //jsonpCallback: 'flightstatus',
      success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                  
      error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); }
    });  

</script>  
</html>
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the returned data? It might be helpful to add that to your question instead of refering to another one (that doesn't help).

Comment: I'll have no problem with the JSON data once I get it back from Flightstats.  I just wanted to make this question as concise, short and as simple as possible.  I referred to the other questions as a reference to make it easy to refer to other answers to a similar question.

Comment: So what is your problem then? The code you posted is working just fine. (after removing the two pieces of whitespace in the URL)

Comment: Hmmmm.  The 2 "white spaces" got there when I pasted into StackOverFlow.  Awesome.....  works for you?  / console.log('success')??

Comment: Yes, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/N4RxM/

Comment: OK.  Now I'm really stumped.  Thankyou.  the jsfiddle works fine.  Looks like I'm doing something really dumb in my head section or something.